# Assign values to autoimplemented property of type string()

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to assign array elements to an auto-implemented property but it is not working.

What I tried:

```
Public Class A
Public Property A() as String = New() {"Hello", "Friend"}
End Class
```

and

```
Public Class A
Public Property A() as String = {"Hello", "Friend"}
End Class
```

But I always get the error that the value of an type 1-dimensional Array of String cann not be converted into string.

Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use

```
Property A As String()
```

instead of

```
Property A() as String
```

Otherwise the compiler assumes a `string` instead of a `string()`.

So this works:

```
Public Class Foo
    Public Property A As String() = {"Hello", "Friend"}
End Class
```

Of course you can also use a constructor:

```
Public Class Foo
    Public Sub New()
        A = {"Hello", "Friend"}
    End Sub
    Public Property A As String()
End Class
```

By the way, interestingly enough it works for fields in both ways:

```
Public B1() As String = {"Hello", "Friend"} ' compiles
Public B2 As String() = {"Hello", "Friend"} ' compiles
```

Side-note: a property should not  have the same name as the class. Therefore i've renamed the class.